# Soundtrack of K: Return of Kings at the beginning of Episode 2

Tags: music, k-project

What is the title for the song in *K: Return of Kings* episode 2 right at the beginning of the episode where Shiro falls from the sky ?

Answer (score 1):

The song is called 'The Dresden Slate'. It's from the *K: Return of Kings OST*, a full list of which can be found [here](http://k-project.wikia.com/wiki/Music#K_Return_of_Kings_Original_Soundtrack). Here's the song posted on Youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_frSptNITo